# css "if has" class, use other media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media queries for site:

from 580 - smartphones
from 580 to 930 - tablets
from 930 - desktops

But one page has another media queries:

from 670 - smartphones
from 670 to 930 - tablets
from 930 - desktops

How can I do it, if a  has class "cart-page" use this media queries or if it hasn't use another.

I don't want to copy past my styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `if` check in CSS. You would have to use the classes inside the same media query to differentiate between the two (or more) modes. it's better to give the whole wrapper element a class for each mode. for example, you could give the `body` tag or better, the `html` tag a class which represent something else for each category of your choosing, and with that you could work down the selectors.

In your case, you could give a class to all pages, and replace it with a specific class to that special page of yours, and work with that.

#### Example

```
@media screen and(max-width:580px){
    .allPages a{ color:green; }
}

@media screen and(max-width:670px){
    .specialPage a{ color:red; }
}
```